# Upgrade of ojdbc7 driver from 11 to 12.1.0.2 encountered with exception

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, spring-jdbc

We are trying to upgrade ojdbc driver from 11 to 12.1.0.2 on tomcat 7. Its working on our local machine (windows 7 OS). When we deployed the code on tomcat installed on linux servers , we are getting the below exception

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver
>   class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

We checked for the `WEb-inf/lib` folder, jdbc jars are in place

Comment: What is your Java version and ojdbc driver version e.g. `ojdbc8.jar`?. Please also include the full stack of the exception.

Comment: Typo: `OralceDriver` should be `OracleDriver`, and btw you should load `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

Comment: sorry its just typo when I entered exception stack on this page. But  there is no typo in code on my machine. We are getting this  exception for 12.1.0.2 . Its working fine for 11.Thanks for the reply

Comment: We are using java 8 with ojdbc7